# What is the algorithm for storing the pixels in an oval in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, drawing, points

How would one draw an oval in JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SVG](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/) .. or tiny divs and [bresenham](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) .. or check the [Javascript VectorGraphics library](http://www.walterzorn.com/jsgraphics/jsgraphics_e.htm)

Comment: I was more looking for the math behind it...but yeah that's probably in the Javascript VectorGraphics library...

Answer (score 0):

More-or-less crossplatform way to do vector graphics is to use [Dojo GFX](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/gfx) ([tests](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/gfx/tests/), [demos](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/gfx/demos/), [ellipse example](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/gfx/tests/test_bezier.html) — all those links point to the test/debug server, can be slow at times).